# Why is canvas blurry?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have been playing around with the canvas and have noticed that almost everything drawn onto the canvas is blurry in comparison to just plain css. I have looked at the other answers on Stack about straddling the cordinates:

**instead of this:**

context.moveTo(10, 0);

context.lineTo(10, 30);

**do this:**

context.moveTo(10.5, 0);

context.lineTo(10.5, 30);

I tried this and it actually made my line more blurry...

Here is an image of my issue:

[image]

As u can hopefully see, the line on the left (which was drawn to the canvas) is way more blurry than just a normal CSS line.

Here is my markup and JS:

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(40, 40);
ctx.lineTo(40, 140);
ctx.strokeStyle = "#0499ff";
ctx.lineWidth = 10;

ctx.stroke();
```

Hope this is enough info. I really want to understand this issue! Thanks in advance!
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7NLkH/

UPDATE:

I am also on a macbook retina... Could that be the issue? If so what are some ways to get around blurry lines?

Comment: Because your eyesight is fading :)

Comment: LOL it could be i guess. I just don't understand, because all the "possible duplicates of this question" state that you should just move over in .5 pixels to straddle. This isn't working for me.

Comment: In your screenshot, your line is quite blurry, but testing on my machine yields a blade-sharp line. Check your zoom levels, if you don't have something like 100.1%

Comment: It's blade sharp in the fiddle you linked.  I wonder if it's a resolution issue on your monitor?

Comment: I updated my question, I am on a retina display.

Comment: Please refrain from providing useless detail like "retina display" It means nothing, at most it's like you're a shill for Apple marketing.

Comment: lol ok... im on a 15-inch (2880 x 1800) display

Comment: The "duplicate" question does not solve this problem and the question should not have been closed (voting for reopen). The reason is that retina display uses double the resolution (pixel aspect ratio is 2:1) so you need to define your canvas width double resolution then use CSS to set the intended resolution. (ie. `canvas.width = 600; canvas.style.width = '300px';` etc.). (in *addition* to that translating half pixel *may* help).